# Не работает header

Tags: php

При нажатии на кнопку(один из товаров) нужно что бы header перенаправлял например на страницу http://localhost/my_shop/index.php?id_good=19&id_cat=44&p=0 в зависимости от того на какой товар был нажат без `header` все работает, но так же и работает повторная отправка формы,

ОШИБКА заключается в том что, ни один браузер не может отобразить страницу. Эта проблема может возникать при отключении или запрещении принятия кук. выдает браузер

```
    if(isset($_GET['id_good'])){
    $tovar = $_GET['id_good'];
    $stranitsa = $_GET['p'];
         $sql = "SELECT quantity FROM goods LIMIT 1"; 
          $res = mysql_query($sql);
       $row_good = mysql_fetch_array($res);

         $sql = "UPDATE goods SET quantity=quantity-1 WHERE id_good='$tovar'";
       mysql_query($sql);
    //header("Location: index.php?id_good=$tovar&id_cat=$id_cat&p=$stranitsa");

      }
```

Comment: Включите вывод ошибок в браузер. Вероятно, Вы используете header после того, как поместили данные в вывод.  
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php

Comment: MYSQL DEPRICATED

[depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: это что реклама?

Comment: Больше похоже на совет, и неплохой.

Comment: у меня все ок работает на этой же версии при устаревших разширениях

Comment: Ну, в дальнейшем обновлять php будет проблематично. Это совет на будущее, как сделать лучше... а не как сделать, чтоб вообще работало.

Comment: уже давно обновленное пхп и все ок работает

Comment: @LLIAKAJI ппц. вам на официальном сайте говорят - 

#НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ РАСШИРЕНИЕ MYSQL В НОВОМ КОДЕ.

вы знаете почему ? потому-что это расширение УЖЕ не поддерживается командой разработчиков, просто пока  его компилят, но в нем не исправляют дыры, не следят за тем, чтобы работало адекватно и баги по нему обрабатывать не будут. Если вас это устраивает пользуйтесь на здоровье.

Comment: если бы не устраивало не использовал

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, как бы так намекнуть... Любой сервер (особенно смотрящий во внешку) необходимо периодически латать (обновлять, перенастраивать). И вы гарантированно в будущем наступите на грабли использования php_mysql.  Если этот факт вас устраивает, это очень «хорошо»… Но с таким подходом к безопасности сервера, мня например, совершенно не прельщает тот факт,  что однажды пытаясь оплатить покупку в вашем интернет магазине, мне придется подарить некую сумму со своего счета третьей стороне. Если вам не интересен опыт других людей, возникает резонный вопрос… для чего вы здесь?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему вы редиректите с одной страницу на неё же. Т.е получается циклическое перенаправление. и оно никогда не заканчивается.

Comment: нажимаю на товар появляется вот эта ссылка  http://localhost/my_shop/index.php?id_good=19&id_cat=44&p=0
и хочу что бы после нажатия она и осталась, без header оно так и есть, только повторная отправка формы еще остается, как это можно решить?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по коду и описанию проблемы, вы пытаетесь при нажатии на кнопку товара запустить сторонний скрипт, который получит количество товара из базы, уменьшит его на единицу и вернется на предыдущую страницу с описанием этого товара.

На самом деле, все что вам нужно - это не перезагружая страницу отправить запрос на сервер и после ответа обновить только количество оставшегося товара. AJAX решит и эту проблему играючи.

Если используется чистый JS, могу помочь с реализацией таких запросов. Для jQuery код займет пару строк. Что-то типа этого:

```
$.post("quantity.php", { "id_good": id }, function(data){ $('#quantity').html(data); });
```

Можно пинать, но в мягких тапках.

Comment: Простите, как понять "Можно пинать, но в мягких тапках"?

Comment: Критику приветствую, но умеренную.

Answer (score 0):

Как было уже сказано [[@shurik](/users/1182/shurik)](/users/1182/shurik) - у вас бесконечный редирект.

Простейшее решение - добавить ещё один флаг.

```
    if(isset($_GET['id_good']) && !isset($_GET['redirected'])){
$tovar = $_GET['id_good'];
$stranitsa = $_GET['p'];
     $sql = "SELECT quantity FROM goods LIMIT 1"; 
      $res = mysql_query($sql);
   $row_good = mysql_fetch_array($res);

     $sql = "UPDATE goods SET quantity=quantity-1 WHERE id_good='$tovar'";
   mysql_query($sql);
   header("Location: index.php?id_good=$tovar&id_cat=$id_cat&p=$stranitsa&redirected=1");

  }
```

Comment: уже давно все работает, кстате код и был рабочий просто его нужно было в другой файл определить, все оказалось проще чем было=)

Comment: @Gedweb, странное решение. А если я повторно захотел бы нажать на кнопку товара?